# Bitoperators in C on char*

Tags: c, char, bitwise-operators

Is there a way to to something like:

```
char* a = "Hello";
char* b = NULL;
char* c = a | b;

Result should be c = "Hello";
```

Seems like it does not work with Char*, but is there a way to do something like that?

Comment: you are mixing the notion of address with contents

Comment: What would you expect this to do if a and b both pointed to actual strings?

Comment: Bit operators operate on bits.

Comment: it's highly likely you'll get the same value as a, but this doesn't do what you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is nonsense not only because bitwise operators on pointers would have very... interesting... results, but mainly because **NULL is not guaranteed to be represented by 0**.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible using ternary operators. The code below sets *c* to *b* if *a == NULL* and sets *c* to *a* otherwise.

```
char *c = (a == NULL)? b : a;
```

Now a clarification on bitwise operators: | and & work on the bits of the operands. Suppose we have two variables, a = 10000001 (128) and b = 10000010 (129). *It does not matter the type of a and b, only the bit representation of their values.*

a | b = 10000011, that is, it takes the bitwise OR between the bits of a and b;

a & b = 10000000, that is, it takes the bitwise AND between the bits of a and b;

These operators make sense when you are *working directly with the bits of the value of your variables*. In C, the value of a pointer is the address of a chunk of memory, not the contents of its chunk. Applying a bitwise operation on pointers means applying a bitwise operation on the addresses that they hold. The result of this operation can point to almost anywhere on the memory and using this pointer will probably get you a *Segmentation Fault* (or at least junk data).

Answer (score 0):

The following will set `c` to `a` if it's not null, otherwise set it to `b`:

```
char *c = a ? a : b;
```

This is called the *ternary operator*.